# What is the correct way to write the code for getting layers from the server?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, pyscripter

I'm writing a script to call raster from the server to load them to my MXD file. It is just like when you add the data in Arcmap.

Problem is that the raster I have is on the server.

Is this correct path to retrieve them ?

```
raster = r"S:\Las Cruces SSO\GIS_Master_Data\NAIP_2009\Dona Ana"
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve? Do you have a raster dataset (what format?) stored on another machine and you want to add this raster as a layer to a map document?

Comment: Yes, the S drive is not on my computer so the C drive is my local hard drive .  yes, it is a raster in mr sid format.

Comment: I just test it using this code and this works...import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "S:\Las Cruces SSO\GIS_Master_Data\NAIP_2009\Dona Ana"

RasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()
for rL in RasterList:
    print rL

Comment: Why don't you  test it yourself to see whether it works or not?

Comment: @FaridCher  - Yes I did. The path name worked....

Comment: Have you tested it with UNC path (\\server-name\...). This can complete your question.

Comment: @FaridCher - no.